# Unicode characters not printing properly in terminal python

Tags: python, python-3.x, unicode, printing

I have a really simple program that I wrote to tell me the unicode values for some characters.

Here is the program:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

characters = [u'T', u'ב', u'€', u'木', u'♥']

for character in characters:

    print(character + " has the unicode value :\t"+str(hex(ord(character))) + "\n")
```

and it gives this output:

```
T has the unicode value :   84

ב has the unicode value :   1489

€ has the unicode value :   8364

木 has the unicode value :   26408

♥ has the unicode value :   9829
```

I notice that the output is formatted properly when I copy and paste here but on my computer the second line is displayed like this in the terminal

```
has the unicode value : 1489 ב
```

also I tried putting the output into a file and viewing the file with vim and it also looks like this, with the character that should be printed first being printed last. This leads me to think that it is printing properly but not displaying properly. What could cause this to happen?

Comment: what version of python are you using? If you are using python2 your code should error

Comment: @PadraicCunningham given that there's no `u` in front of what's obviously Unicode, yet it's still giving the correct result from `ord`, I'd say it's Python 3. Which sub-version I don't know.

Comment: @MarkRansom, I wanted to be doubly sure, if the output does not match and it is python3 then the encoding is more than likely the problem

Comment: @PadraicCunningham Python 3, sorry forgot to include that

Comment: @guribe94, where are you running it from?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham From my terminal on an os x machine, with home-brew installed python 3

Comment: @guribe94: The problem might be that `ב` is a Hebrew letter. Hebrew is written from right to left. I don't really know how to fix this but I think there is a Unicode character that determines whether to write from left-to-right, or from right-to-left

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The right-justified behaviour of Hebrew characters can be overridden using the Unicode LEFT-RIGHT OVERRIDE (LRO) character 0x202D.

```
characters = [u'T', u'ב', u'€', u'木', u'♥']

for character in characters:

    print(chr(0x202D) + character + " has the unicode value :\t"+str(hex(ord(character))) + "\n")
```

Gives (on OS X Terminal):

```
‭T has the unicode value :  0x54

‭ב has the unicode value :  0x5d1

‭€ has the unicode value :  0x20ac

‭木 has the unicode value :  0x6728

♥ has the unicode value :   0x2665
```

Thanks to @guribe94 in identifying the issue.

You might find string formatting a little easier to read:

```
    print("%s%s has the unicode value :\t 0x%04x\n" %
        (chr(0x202D), character, ord(character)))
```

Comment: Instead of `chr(0x202D)` you could use `'\u202d'`.

Answer (score 0):

Just replace the first row as:

```
characters = [u'T', u'ב', u'€', u'木', u'♥']
```

Comment: In Python 3 this is not necessary, and in fact will fail in earlier versions.

Comment: It works fine for me in 2.7, why would it fail if it's unicode strings? Actually it crashes if it's not unicode strings.

Comment: This doesn't make a difference and like @MarkRansom said this shouldn't be necessary in python 3 as python 3 treats strings as unicode by default

Comment: @MarkRansom I run it in my "jupyter notebook" and everything is fine.

Comment: @guribe94 it's not necessary in py3, true, but on the contrary to what MarkRansom said this works in < 3 but without unicode it does not.

Comment: @olofom. the OP is using python3 so regardless this answer is not actually relevant

Comment: It's not the answer but the comment I'm talking about. I'm opposing the statement about earlier versions, not the answer itself.

Comment: @olofom what I meant was *not* Python 2, but Python 3 earlier than 3.3. See [PEP 0414](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0414/). Sorry that I was unclear.

Comment: @MarkRansom ah, that makes sense. My bad, I just assumed you meant < 3 :)